# Use OpenCl Global ID as an integer in the kernel

Tags: python, opencl, pyopencl

I just started looking into OpenCl in python using the pyopencl module.

I am interested in generating stuff without any inputs, generating samples of a sine wave for instance.

To do so, all I needed was the global id to make my calculations, but returning the global id result in some fancy numbers. I use the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl

Size = Width*Height

# Get platforms, both CPU and GPU
plat = cl.get_platforms()
GPU = plat[0].get_devices()

#Create context for GPU
ctx = cl.Context(GPU)

# Create queue for each kernel execution
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

mf = cl.mem_flags

# Kernel function
src = '''
__kernel void shader(__global float *result, __global int *width){

int w = *width;
size_t gid = get_global_id(0);

result[gid] = gid;
}
'''

#Kernel function instantiation
prg = cl.Program(ctx, src).build()

#Allocate memory for variables on the device
width_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=np.int32(Width))
result_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, Size*8)

# Call Kernel. Automatically takes care of block/grid distribution
prg.shader(queue, (Size,), None , result_g, width_g)
result = np.empty((Size,))
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, result, result_g)

Image = result
```

All I do is copy the global id to the buffer object **result_d**, but when I inspect **result**, I get some numbers that are not even integers. I also tried setting my buffer to an integer instead of float, but the result was still the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `result` in the OpenCL kernel is of type `float` and the `result` on the host side is of type `double`.

Specify the host buffer to be `float` to fix the problem:

```
result = np.empty((Size,),dtype=np.float32)
```